# Maths subscript and superscript shortcuts out of equations?

Tags: windows, microsoft-office, microsoft-onenote-2013

Is it possible in Microsoft one note to make e.g. V_0 (followed by a press of the space bar) to automatically V with a subscript of 0 and likewise V^0 to go to V with a superscript of 0 (not just for this specfic example with V and 0 but in general)?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer,

Apply or remove superscript formatting from the selected text --> `CTRL+SHIFT+=`

Apply or remove subscript formatting from the selected text --> `CTRL+=`

Highlight the text which should be super/sub script and follow the key combinations.

Here is the reference [link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Keyboard-shortcuts-in-OneNote-2013-65dc79fa-de36-4ca0-9a6e-dfe7f3452ff8).

Comment: @Quantum spaghettification did this answer worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this should be possible. Assuming you're on the latest version of desktop OneNote, you can use the equation editor, which contains a bunch of these LaTeX style shortcuts.

First, you'll need to insert an equation, which can be done by either using the ribbon or the ALT+= shortcut.

_ and ^ will produce subscript and superscript after you type a space. There's other nifty shortcuts too; \pi for example will produce a pi symbol, for example. [This superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/340650/type-math-formulas-in-microsoft-word-the-latex-way) actually has a more thorough description.

Hope this helps!