# Proper way to typeset units in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, latex, typography

I have to typeset a scientific paper in MS Word (2013). As a latex user I am used to typeset units with the siunitx package to get proper typesetting. What would be the correct way in word to do this?

**Edit** I have the same problem again (now using word 2019), but the [old solution](https://superuser.com/a/1024429/53616) doesn't seem to work anymore, since the link in the answer seems to be broken. But maybe there are better even better options in 2022 than in 2016.

**Edit 2** To respond to the comments, I try to give some more details.

The main point is, that units have to be typeset whereas variables often are typeset slanted. One reason is that you can distinguish between variables and units if they occur in the same expression. Compare for example the [NIST Guide (Sec 6)](https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/pdf/sp811.pdf) for this convention.

For LaTeX there is a package called [`siunitx`](https://ftp.mpi-inf.mpg.de/pub/tex/mirror/ftp.dante.de/pub/tex/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx/siunitx.pdf) which takes care for this (as well as other things as spacing or rounding if you want). Then you may write for example

```
v = \SI{5}{\m\per\s}
```

Meaning that the speed v is equal to 5 meter per second. In standard LaTeX config, this would result in

[image]

I.e. the variable v slanted and the units upright. A good editor autocompletes the `\SI` macro so that you don't need to type `\SI{...}` manually.

Now if I try to typeset this equation in Word (as an unexperienced word user), I start a new equation (using [LaTeX input](https://superuser.com/a/509805/53616) as default), and type:

```
v = 5 \frac{m}{s}
```

If I then convert it to "professional", everything is slanted (as if m and s were variables).

So, what is a good way to get this result without too much pain?

Another problem is to convert existing expressions with to this convention. In LaTeX you can think about a clever regular expression like [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/5350/2323), but how would you go in word?

**Edit 3**

I just noticed, that it works do type something like (in linear mode)

```
v = 5 \mathrm{\frac{m}{s}}
```

to get the desired result (that like I would in put units in webpages with mathjax interpreter like physics.stackexchange). Is it possible to define a keyboard shortcut for `\mathrm{}` (with cursor between the brackets)? I also thought about editing the underlying xml document (docx is essentially a bunch of zipped xml files) with a good editor, but the xml document is rather unreadable.

Comment: Could you please explain your problem for non-users of latex? Also it would help giving a link to the answer that your mention.

Comment: An example of what exactly you need to do would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Word+Equate Word Add-In: http://www.wordequate.com/. It is for targeted for another task (inlined calculation), but displays values with units well.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward is to use the inbuilt equation editor, which you access from `insert -> Equation`. This will open the equation tab, which normally is hidden.

You can insert your equation (or just units) in Unicode or LaTeX format.

[image]

To access the options or change the font, click on the dropdown next to "Conversions". (Red square in the image below).

[image]

If you need something more sophisticated, there are some paid plugins out there, but nothing I could specifically recommend.

Comment: For me the drop down menu contains only Cambria Math (nothing to choose). Furthermore this seems to apply to the whole equation and not only to the part of the unit. Finally if it would work, this would mean that I had to do several clicks each time to format the unit, which seems to be hard work if you have hundrets of equations.